# PowerShell Exception calling "readkey"

Tags: powershell, server, minecraft, powershell-ise, minecraft-fabric

Having issue with one arg in my minecraft server powershell script

line reads as follows
Exception calling "ReadKey" with "1" argument(s): "The method or operation is not implemented."
At F:\BMC2_FABRIC_1.20.1_Server_Pack_v24\start.ps1:102 char:6

Line 102 char 6 is as follows
$Host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") > $null

I tried removing the periods in the line and shifting the first character around one or two spaces, to no avail.

Comment: `$Host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey` is not implemented in powershell ISE. Use powershell.exe instead and it shouldnt fail in that line.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).